# Creating an interface with an abstract method

Tags: java, interface, return, double, abstract

I am to create an interface named Payable that has an abstract method named getPayableAmount that returns a double and takes no parameters, did I do this correctly? It seems far to simple to be right. Shouldn't there be a return statement or something? when i added one i got an error

```
public interface Payable 
{
  abstract double getPaymentAmount();



}
```

Comment: Methods in interfaces are already `abstract`. You can add some implementation in the interface by using `default` methods, but that's only available if you use Java 8: [Default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html) says this:

**9.4 Abstract Method Declarations:**

> For compatibility with older versions of the Java platform, it is
>   permitted but discouraged, as a matter of style, to redundantly
>   specify the abstract modifier for methods declared in interfaces.

You also don't need to specify `public` for interface methods.

See the [documentation for Defining an Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html):

> All abstract, default, and static methods in an interface are
>   implicitly `public`, so you can omit the public modifier.

```
public interface Payable
{
  double getPaymentAmount();
}
```

You'll need an implementation of the interface to actually implement the logic. For example something like this:

```
public class PayableImpl implements Payable 
{
  double getPaymentAmount() 
  {
     // actual implementation that returns the payment amount
  }
}
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, it is discouraged to write "abstract" or "public" as this verbiage implies that methods within the interface cannot be abstract or public if the user omits them.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to provide the ***abstract*** keyword in an Interface method.
All methods in an interface is an abstract method. No concrete methods are allowed in an interface.

An **abstract class** can have both **abstract method** and **Concrete method**. In that condition we need to specify if a method is an abstract one or a concrete one.

```
public interface Payable 
{
    double getPaymentAmount();
}

public abstract class Payable
{
    //This is an abstract method. It has to be implemented by the extending class
    abstract public double getPaymentAmount(); 

    //This is a concrete method. It can be inherited by the extending class
    private int CalucateSum(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

Comment: You really don't need the `public` modifier for method signatures. All interface methods are implicitly `public`.

Comment: That's correct.
private method in an interface is of no use at all.
If we need to implement an interface, it should be public in the interface. :)

Comment: It is needed for the interface header though

Comment: If u are writing Java 8, then the `abstract` keyword is now required since new Java 8+ interfaces can now contain `static` and `default` methods which  `default` methods may need not implemented in a concrete `class` so @Bimzee needs an update~

Comment: @Jose Mhlanga : Before Java 8, interfaces does not have a default method. From Java 8 onward yes I too agree. In Technology world, definitions will & should get updated from time to time. Thanks for pointing.